# Jar not using contained classes or namespace collision

Tags: java, jar, namespaces, collision

I'm using netbeans to generate a web service client from a WSDL doc.

The client works fine until we put it in our production environment. The jars were generated against javax.ws.xxxxx classes from jaxws-api.jar and jaxb-api.jar, which we placed in out production classpath.

In our production environment we have other code that depends on xfire libraries. When we attempt to instantiate SubmissionAPI(), we are getting a NoClassDefFound Exception. I'm pasting the stack trace below.

UBLSoapTest class appears to call the correct 'Service' class, but the 'Service' class
is calling org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.Provider.

I've checked the source for javax.xml.ws.Service, and it has 'import javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider;'

We've tried assembling the jar with the javax.xxxx classes inside and still get the same result. I suspect we need to set a classpath in the manifest file, but I'm not sure what needs to be there.

```
FAIL: Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.JAXWSHelper
org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:33)
org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:53)
org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:32)
javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
org.ubl.soap.test.SubmissionAPI.<init>(SubmissionAPI.java:44)
```

I'm a bit at a loss of even where to look from here.

We've tried setting classpath in the manifest, with little success.

The basic jar structures we've tries are:

```
/org/xxxx
/META-INF/xxx
```

and

```
/org/xxx
/META-INF/xxx
/javax/xxx
```

and

```
/org/xxx
/META-INF/xxx
/jaxws-api.jar
/jaxb.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the impl jar for JAX-WS. If you are relying on Codehaus to provide the impl, you might want to make sure their impl works. According to their site, it's a newly supported component.

The alternative is to provide your own impl jar and put it in the class path so JAX-WS interfaces are found there. But usually the app server where you deploy your web service app should include the impl in its class path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Are the two api jars not the impl? If not, do we need to copy the entirety of the /lib folder from the javaws-ri download? Or something else? (Obviously the xfire isn't working for this build )

Comment: Usually any jar that has the name "api" in it, is just the interfaces to get your code compiled. The jaxws-api.jar may just include interfaces and no implementation. So the class loader will search your class path to find the first implementation, and probably picks it up from Codehaus jars which may not be a complete implementation of JAX-WS. (but then again, it might be. The reason I suspected that is because I read on their site that it's newly added.)

Comment: Like I said, as far as I know, all JEE app servers are supposed to provide implementation for JAX-WS. If not, try downloading the reference implementation: https://jax-ws.java.net/  -- which app server do you use?

Comment: I missed the second part of your comment. Looks like you are already looking at reference implementation. You don't need to copy all the jars in the lib directory. Try first by copying jaxb-impl.jar which includes the implementation. If you get more NoClassDefFoundError, search for it in the lib directory to see what else you need to copy.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to accept the answer, but like all production, this was not our only issue. You were correct that we needed the jaxb-impl.jar in our classpath. We also found that we had NOT included the api jars in the classpath. There was a properties xml file that we needed to list the files to have them picked up. (Don't ask, we're running an extremely customized tomcat for our java server). Thanks again for the help!